# Google SDK upload progress bar using Laravel 4

Tags: jquery, ajax, upload, google-api, progress-bar

I am using Google SDK. Im trying to upload the progress in my resumableUpload function in my Laravel controller
and i want to show it in my upload modal
This is my code:

in my Main Controller

```
$upload= $this->google->resumableUpload($file,$parent);
```

in my index view
i have an upload modal

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'/upload/'.$files['upload'][0],'files'=>true)) }}
{{ Form::file('files','',array('name'=>'files','class'=>'')) }}
{{ Form::submit('Upload', array('id'=>'uploadBtn','class'=>'btn btn-block btn-primary')) }}
```

how can i run the progress bar when user clicks upload?
should i put jquery in my upload modal
pls help.